# What is the difference between DatatableRowchanging Event and DataTableRowChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I am trying understand the difference between `RowChanging` and `Rowchanged` event of datatable. I have Checked the MSDN blog but could not find any practical difference.

Here is what i got:

1. Both Use same `Datarowchangeeventargs` : So they have same set of event data.
   namely ; `e.Action` and `e.row`.

In watch Window i checked if there are any changes to these event data but they were similar. If there would have been Cancel in `RowChanging` then it would have meant about validating.

So all in all , I  m confused why the two event if they meant the same.

Please clear my confusion.

**Here's my difference** that i found based on the pointers that i got from answers.

I added few rows to column and called both events. I tried doing e.Row.RejectChanges() on both changing and changed event 
thats when i realised that e.Row is actually the proposed row. 
so Rejectchanges was giving me error "Cannot Canceledit() inside rowchanging event". 
But it was allowing reject to happen in RowChanged Event.
so the following sequence happened:
1.RowChangingEvent 
  e.Action=Added (as i was adding multiple rows to table)
  e.Row.RowState=Detached.
2. RowChanged Event
  e.Action=Added
  e.Row.RowState=Added (in Red as it was changed here and added to datatable)

As for the Exception :
I recieved "Cannot cAll CancelEdit() in rowchanging event"

In rowChanged Event i got "This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row."

Please guide me with the above row changed Event Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RowChanged Event occurs **after** a DataRow has been successfully changed.

The RowChanging Event occurs during the change of the DataRow.  This will give you the opportunity to execute code before the row itself is changed.

Comment: Both occur one after the other thats true but both of them have same event data. My question is what's the use of two event's when you can do the same with one. So you can execute code in both and do whatever execution and they both will be same.

Comment: Maybe in the context you are thinking of it, your application for it will be the same.  However, you can throw an exception in the RowChanging Event, which would prevent the RowChanged Event from firing at all (maybe you are doing some sort of validation).  If the validation passes, you can use the RowChanged Event to do whatever you needed, otherwise throw an exception.  It all depends on what you are wanting to do when the row is changed.  They can both be used to do the same things in some instances.

Comment: As a note, in general many objects in the CLR will include these pairs of events where one event is intended for before the object is changed, and the other event intended for after. The past/present tense of the command should clue you in on that.

Comment: Thanks for the information on checking exception i tried it. then i realised where the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx):

`DataTable.RowChanging` Event occurs when a `DataRow` is changing.

while

`DataTable.RowChanged` Event occurs after a `DataRow` has been changed successfully.

If you throw exception in changing event you can retire changes. Changed
events you can use to make changes in other tables but you can't (in simple
way) resign.

Yes, it `True` that both contain the same event data i.e. `e.Action` and `e.Row`; but it is more important that what operations you want to do at what point of time.

Means `OnChanging` event the data is not validated yet. So if you will do any code change at this stage then the data might not persist if validation gets failed. While in `OnChanged` event you can change the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Onchanging event is not validated so how do we make the validation false. since it has not e.Cancel how do we do it?

Comment: You can use e.Row.AcceptChanges() AND e.Row.RejectChanges() for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know to use Accept and Reject Changes that definitly helped me find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx) :

**RowChanging** : Occurs when a change has been submitted for a DataColumn value or the RowState of a DataRow in the DataTable.

**RowChanged** : Occurs after a DataColumn value or the RowState of a DataRow in the DataTable has been changed successfully. In this event we can tell to the app what will do next ..

([example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged.aspx))